# MySQL InnoDB Gap Lock on Update with where clause by PK?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, timeout, locking, innodb

I'm getting locks in update operations that doesn't seem to be related to each other.

This is the DB Context:

- MySQL 5.7
- InnoDB engine
- Read Committed Isolation Level
- Optimistic Locking concurrency control in the application

The table structure is something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `external_user` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_user_status` (`status`),
  KEY `idx_user_id` (`user_id`) USING BTREE,
);
```

The structure's been simplified. The real one has more attributes and some FKs to other tables.

The process is something like this:

**Process 1**

```
BEGIN;
update external_user 
    set user_id=33333
    where (id in (400000, 400002, 400028............., 420000))
and user_id = 22222;
```

This is a long running query that modifies around 20k rows. Using between is not an option because we don't update all the consecutive records.

At the same time a second process starts.

**Process 2**

```
BEGIN;
update external_user 
set status='disabled', user_id = 44444 
where id = 10000;
```

It turns out that this second update is waiting for the first one to complete. So there's a lock held in the first query.

I've been reading a lot about locking in MySQL, but I couldn't find anything about updates that in where clause have a PK filter with in operator and another filter by an attribute that has an  non-unique index (that is also being changed in the set clause).

Is the first query obtaining a gap lock because of the non-unique index filter? Is it possible? Even though the PK is provided as a filter?

Note: I don't have access to the engine in order to obtain more detailed information.

Comment: Could you use `WHERE id BETWEEN 400000 AND 420000`. Does that solve the problem?

Comment: Nope, I can't. I didn't specify that but not all the range is covered. I'll edit the question.